# A way to store a frequently queried column in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate

I have a query that involves finding response times several times in a row, like so:

```
ROUND(AVG(T.FinishTime-T.StartTime),3) AS 'Average', MAX(T.FinishTime-T.StartTime) AS 'Max', MIN(T.FinishTime-T.StartTime)
```

Now, I don't fully understand how SQL processes this stuff in the background, but from my general knowledge of coding, is it not better to make the subtraction *T.FinishTime-T.StartTime* more efficient? i.e. can the calculation be done once and then the aggregates found on that list of calculations? Or is it already done this way? I just want to try and cut my queries down into more efficient and readable chunks. I thought at first a view of *T.FinishTime-T.StartTime* could be made and that aggregates carried out on this, but then I read that views still calculate each time they are used.

Help appreciated!

Comment: This is not a very expensive repetition of effort in the overall scheme of things. I'd say to spend your time optimizing something else. The group by clause might be such a place.

Comment: Fair enough, it just seemed to me like it might've taken longer than it needed to. Yeah, I have a group by in the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that calculation such a simple expression slows down your application by *any* significant amount?

Premature optimization is the root of all evil, they say. You may be wasting your time on something completely ineffectual. Profile first, optimize later. If you don't profile, *don't* optimize, period.